# Listar el nombre de los departamentos que no tengan empleados con cierto apellido

Tags: sql, sql-server

Intento filtrar los departamentos de una tabla, por el apellido que esta en otra tabla y se conectan por una tabla intermedia. Pero cuando hago el `having`, me desarma la agrupación y me lista todos los departamentos

```
select a.dept_name
from departments as a left join dept_emp as b on a.dept_no=b.dept_no
left join employees as c on b.emp_no=c.emp_no
group by a.dept_name, c.last_name
having c.last_name <> 'valenzuela'
```

[image: addjunto relaciones]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: seria un poco mas facil sabiendo las relaciones....

Comment: Probaste agregando una cláusula WHERE y quitando HAVING?

Comment: Si, intente un where c.last_name <> 'valenzuela'. y claro me filtra los valenzuelas que tengo pero como RRHH, RRHH, informatica, informatica, gerencia,gerencia,gerencia.

Se supone que me debería regresar solo dep, informatica y gerencia. y como tengo valenzuelas en RRHH no me los debería listar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias a los respondieron, me ayudo mucho a encontrar una solución. Lo que tenia que hacer realmente era esto:

```
select a.dept_no,
a.dept_name                                                     --Lista los departamentos
from departments as a                                           --de la tabla departamentos
left join dept_emp as b on a.dept_no=b.dept_no                  --Join dept_emp
where 
a.dept_no not in(select dept_no from employees as b             --Suprime los departamentos que traiga el subquery
                inner join dept_emp as c on b.emp_no=c.emp_no 
                where last_name='valenzuela')
group by a.dept_no, a.dept_name
order by a.dept_no asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ubicar en una primer instancia los departamentos que si tienen un `valenzuela` en su nómina y luego buscar aquellos que no se encuentren en este conjunto:

```
select a.dept_name
       from departments a 
       where a.dept_no not in (
                     select b.dept_no
                            from dept_emp b 
                            inner join employees c 
                               on b.emp_no=c.emp_no
                            where c.last_name = 'valenzuela'
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Y si quitas "c.last_name" de tu group by, y en vez de having usas el where, algo así:

```
    select a.dept_name
    from departments as a left join dept_emp as b on a.dept_no=b.dept_no
    left join employees as c on b.emp_no=c.emp_no
    where c.last_name <> 'valenzuela'
    group by a.dept_name
```